# How to use gltf-validator package in Angular app

Tags: typescript, npm, angular7, gltf

I've added gltf-validator (version 2.0.0-dev.2.7) to my angular project using node. In my component ts file I'm trying to include it with

```
import * as validator from 'gltf-validator'
```

The app compiles with no issues but in the browser console I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
>   
>   at Object../node_modules/gltf-validator/gltf_validator.dart.js (gltf_validator.dart.js:1)
>   
>   at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>   
>      at Module../node_modules/gltf-validator/module.mjs (module.mjs:1)
>      at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>   
>      at Module../src/app/inspector/inspector.component.ts (main.js:673)
>   
>      at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>   
>      at Module../src/app/app.component.ts (main.js:113)
>   
>      at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>   
>      at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:13)
>   
>      at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)

I've tried adding some polyfills but there are several variables in gltf_validator.dart.js that are undefined at runtime.

It seems gltf-validator works in a pure javascript environment with

```
var validator = require('gltf-validator')
```

I tried it this way too without success.

How do I use a package like gltf-validator in an Angular7 project?

Comment: May be worth filing a bug — this looks like the package may be incompatible with webpack, or some particular webpack setup.